# Click on one button multiple times and mySql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, button

I'm making sort of generator. On each click on `button` it need to read me a record from database and show it in `textbox1` and `textbox2`.

For now i know how to read from database but how to on each click show different values

```
Public Class form1
    Dim mysqlconnection As MySqlConnection
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        mysqlconnection = New MySqlConnection()
        mysqlconnection.ConnectionString = " Hidden "
        Try
            mysqlconnection.Open()
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & myerror.Message)
        End Try
        Dim myadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim sqlquary = "SELECT * FROM bazatestna.Users"
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand
        command.Connection = mysqlconnection
        command.CommandText = sqlquary
        myadapter.SelectCommand = command
        Dim mydata As MySqlDataReader
        mydata = command.ExecuteReader()
        If mydata.HasRows = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Database has no records")
        Else
            'Ths is the part where i need to show values on click
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I would love on load to read all data from `mysql` database and then whenever i click on button to show one record from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it: I declare a variable and place it under Form1 Class:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim cnt as Integer = 1
```

Then add 1 increment of cnt inside your button click event:

```
cnt +=1
```

Then modify your query string to add limit:

```
Dim sqlquary = "SELECT * FROM bazatestna.Users Limit " & cnt & ", 1"
```

To make the program run a little faster, move your connection declarations to the form load event:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mysqlconnection = New MySqlConnection()
    mysqlconnection.ConnectionString = " Hidden "
    Try
        mysqlconnection.Open()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & myerror.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: That was a  great method. Great job. Just one thing more and i will mark this as answer. Now my entire code looks like this. [Pastebin 38  lines ](http://pastebin.com/caJbycUF) . Is there any way to put this "database reading" on form load event. So when i click on buttons it will work the way faster. Thanks